# Complicated Wordpress scenario trying to get https up and running

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403, mixed-content

I honestly have no idea about a more tentative and suggestive title, so... sorry to all moderators in advance.

Ok, so I configured properly Let's Encrypt to my website with Nginx. Once I finished, I see the website without CSS, JS, etc. in a typical `blocked:mixed:content` *(BMC)* problem. BMC is easily fixable, you check wordpress URL configuration plus one or two more stuffs.

So here's where things start to get complicated. Only after I successfully logged into my `wp-admin`, Wordpress shows me a `Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.`, which in the back it's a 403 error. At that time, error.log wont show anything, however access.log show this:

```
160.160.160.160 - - [26/Dec/2016:11:43:59 -0600] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/2.0" 403 1826 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
160.160.160.160 - - [26/Dec/2016:11:43:59 -0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" 200 159 "https://www.paradisearenasblancas.com/wp-admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
```

*(Fake IPs BTW)*

So far everything is a mere information and I can't see a sole useful information about the error in question.

I have configured my Wordpress installation with the old `http` URL, so after I can't enter the dashboard, I can edit those URLs directly with MySQL or manually adding it in `wp-config`. The problem with that is that it gives me the `net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error in browsers. So it's kind a bottleneck scenario, and I have no idea what to do.

I can't find an error in my `website.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-www.mywebsite.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name  www.mywebsite.com;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/mywebsite.com/;
    index index.php index.html;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error-paradise.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-paradise.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

            # Wide-open CORS config for nginx
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://www.mywebsite.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type,Accept';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
        }

    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }
}
```

Another thing I did was to move all plugins from `plugins` directory and nothing, everything still the same.

I have no idea what else to do. Any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT:
It seems to be the theme I'm using. I've tried to move its directory and when Wordpress changes to the next default theme, everything is working fine. If I copy again the theme's directory to `themes/`, the same problem will start. Since I have lots of `blocked:mixed:content` errors, I'm searching within theme directory using `grep -rnw '/usr/share/nginx/html/website.com/wp-content/themes/themename/' -e 'http'`and found a huge amount of lines containing `http`. I know there's a lot of plugins that fixes this, but since I'm getting error 403 once I'm logged in into wp-admin, how can I replace all that `http` into `https`?

Comment: what actully happen

Comment: I have not read the question. Have you cleared you browser cache?

Comment: Yes @ILoveCSS, I cleared it, and nothing.

Comment: There's one more thing I can suggest, open a new incognito window and try. Notice that a new incognito window differs from a new incognito tab.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @ILoveCSS. An incognito window shows the same.

Comment: Did you modify URLs at general settings? I guess they should be "HTTPS://whatever...".

Comment: Yes @FelipeAlamedaA, as I said before, I do it with MySQL or directly in wp-admin.php, but then I got net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

TO enable SSL for wordpress, you can do any of the two below

1. Edit both your SITE and HOME URL settings in the **Settings -> General** section of your wordpress dashboard, changing the **http** to **https.**
2. Edit your wp-config.php and define both the **WP_SITEURL** and **WP_HOME**

   **`define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com' );`** and **`define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );`**

You should also add this to your wp-config.php force ssl for wp-admin

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```